# Какими модулями реализовать загрузку и скачивание изображений на Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пользователь выгружает аватарку через node.js в удаленную файловую систему рядом с базой данных, после этого каждый сеанс загружает ее обратно. Какими модулями node.js можно осуществлять одноразовую передачу файлов jpg?

Comment: как вариант использовать multer https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `node-wget`:

```
var wget = require('node-wget')

var url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG"
var dest = "./picture.png"

wget({ url, dest }, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) throw error
  console.log("Downloaded")
})
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101217/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy------).

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобятся модули **fs** - для работы с файлами (например, перемещения, переименования), **formidabble** - модуль для работы с мультипарт-формами, позволяет отдельно обрабатывать текстовые поля колбеками `form.on('field', function (field, value) {` и файлы, например, картинки колбеками `form.on('file', function (field, file) {` . Для отдачи картинок во фронтенд вам понадобится **node-static**. Для сохранения адресов картинок (чтобы отрисовать во фронте нужную картинку), надо запомнить местонахождение картинки в базе данных, для этого можно использовать монгу и модуль для неё **mongoose**. Так же для пользователей можно для каждого сделать собственную папку на серваке (можно на основном, а можно и на специальном серваке для картинок и файлов), назвав её, например, уникальным id пользователя, так аватарку можно будет не только найти по базе данных, но и придумать некое АПИ.